# raise ValueError(f"x_max is less than or equal to x_min for bbox {bbox}.")

Tags: bounding-box

I got this error

> raise ValueError(f"x_max is less than or equal to x_min for bbox {bbox}.")
> ValueError: x_max is less than or equal to x_min for bbox (tensor(0.3896), tensor(0.6458), tensor(0.3896), tensor(0.6458), tensor(1)).

This is my code:

```
def get_transform(train):
  if train:
    return A.Compose(
      [
        
        A.HorizontalFlip(0.5),
        # ToTensorV2 converts image to pytorch tensor without div by 255
        ToTensorV2(p=1.0) 
      ],
      bbox_params={'format': 'pascal_voc', 'label_fields': ['labels']}
    )
  else:
    return A.Compose(
      [ToTensorV2(p=1.0)],
      bbox_params={'format': 'pascal_voc', 'label_fields': ['labels']}
    )
```